# Golang removing nil from slice of interface{}

Tags: go, slice

What is the best way to remove "nil" from slice of interface{} and generating a new slice of interface{}?

```
 Slice := []interface{}{1, nil, "string", nil}
```

Nothing good comes to my mind ?

Comment: I did loop through range and check for nil.

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 8):

```
newSlice := make([]interface{}, 0, len(Slice))
for _, item := range Slice {
    if item != nil {
        newSlice = append(newSlice, item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah my issue was missing that 0 while doing make()

Comment: @James, `make([]interface, 0)` works exactly the same, this just pre-allocates the cap. In most code I would probably just use `var newSlice []interface`, and let append allocate as needed since it rarely matters.

Comment: also, in-place filter if order doesn't matter: https://play.golang.org/p/IWBeCs4Cwu

Comment: and for thoroughness, in-place filter maintaining order: https://play.golang.org/p/HUmUwYAMRq

Answer (score 4):

## go1.21+

[As of go1.21](https://go.dev/doc/go1.21#slices), you can use [the standard `slices` package](https://pkg.go.dev/slices) to do this. For older versions of golang, you can still use [the `golang.org/x/exp/slices` package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices) that later became that standard package.

```golang
    things := []interface{}{
        nil,
        1,
        nil,
        "2",
        nil,
        3,
        nil,
    }

    things = slices.DeleteFunc(
        things,
        func(thing interface{}) bool {
            return thing == nil
        },
    )

    things = slices.Clip(things)

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", things)
```

Output:

```
[]interface {}{1, "2", 3}
```

You can play with that [here](https://go.dev/play/p/T0isvu7az_o).

## Original Answer

Unless needed for other reasons, this can be done without allocating a new slice:

```golang
    things := []interface{}{
        nil,
        1,
        nil,
        "2",
        nil,
        3,
        nil,
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(things); {
        if things[i] != nil {
            i++
            continue
        }

        if i < len(things)-1 {
            copy(things[i:], things[i+1:])
        }

        things[len(things)-1] = nil
        things = things[:len(things)-1]
    }

    things = things[:len(things):len(things)]

    fmt.Printf("%#v", things)
```

Output:

```
[]interface {}{1, "2", 3}
```

You can play with that [here](https://play.golang.org/p/NX1eXZfClzX), and you can find more information about slice operations [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use type switches like this example:

```
slice := []interface{}{1, nil, "string", nil}
newSlice := make([]interface{}, 0, len(slice))

for _, val := range(slice){
    switch val.(type) {
        case string, int: // add your desired types which will fill newSlice
            newSlice = append(newSlice, val)
    }
}

fmt.Printf("newSlice: %v\tType: %T\n", newSlice, newSlice)
```

Output:

```
newSlice: [1 string]    Type: []interface {}
```

You can see the full example within [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yNiuA4CmN_)